# Deleting a row form SQLite and update value?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database as shown below .

```
------------------
name    |    position
------------------
a              1 
b              2
c              3     .<----
d              4
f              5
```

I want that when a row is deleted . (Row c)

I know how delete a row .
when delet row c:
sqlite is blow

```
------------------
name    |    position
------------------
a              1 
b              2
d              4
f              5
```

But I do not want this result.

i want to
The result is as shown below

```
------------------
name    |    position
------------------
a              1 
b              2
d              3
f              4
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? Please make it more clearer

Comment: I edit more detail for my question

Comment: @anjeli after deleting row, just insert and update it again, you will get new position.

Comment: This feels like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

you have to execute this query :

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET position = position - 1
WHERE position > x
```

replace `myTable` with your table name. and  replace `x` with position of deleted row.

Comment: Thank you ..
 write Your answer may be as follows:
database.excute ("UPDATE T1 SET position=")

Comment: oky...but   i when write:dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE List_qusition SET position='"+( cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("position"))-1) +"' WHERE heart> "+p+";"); program is exception